# android intent pick item from music browser

Tags: java, android

I want to create an intent to launch a music browser activity (every default music player has such an activity), to pick a track and use it in my application.

I tried using the following code, but the launched activities just list all my music files. Instead, I'd like to be able to browse the music files by albums, artists, geners and playlists, just like the default music players.

My code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType(MediaStore.Audio.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.setData(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Ringtone"), RINGTONE_PICK);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I encounterd the same problem